# How to modify SelectField width in jinja2 template

Tags: css, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I've a Flask based application which has

```
Class itemform:
    item2 = [("a", 'One'), ("b",'Two')]
    items3 = SelectField(u'List items', choices=items2)
```

form similar to  above which is rendered

```
return render_template('item.html', item3=item3)
```

on views.

*item.html* jinja2 template has below content

```
<form action="/items/" method="post" name="items">
    {{ form.item3 }}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="done" />
 </form>
```

the dropdown works properly, I can select the items and gather it 
back it. The Problem is, the width of dropdown box is too small.
option name ("One") is barely visible and become visible only 
when I click the dropdown arrow.

How to change width of it?  Thanks for help!

EDIT:
Here's the link  http://jsfiddle.net/SvN3F/

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle page with rendered html & css please, without it, we can not help you properly :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll trying to create jsfiddle page and update here :)

Comment: okay added the jsfiddle page

Comment: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ASd2Ic9eiBEJ:vaz.net.br/index.pl/jv/20/http/stackoverflow.com/questions/23023788/add-a-css-class-to-an-option-in-a-wtforms-selectfield+&cd=19&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a

Comment: thanks for the link, will read about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean height ? I've added `height:auto` at last line of css, visible [on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SvN3F/1/), it's default css who forced select to have `height:18px`.

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea, select {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: gray;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding: 4px;
    width: 210px;
}
```

Comment: yes, its height. Will make the changes provided by you. Thanks for the help AlexDom :)